# Add element to html using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How do i insert another tag after a specific tag, and remove a tag

example i have this html

```
<p class="cs40314EBF"><span class="cs1B16EEB5">This is an ordinary text.</span></p>
```

and this is the possible output

```
<p class="cs40314EBF"><b>This is an ordinary text.</b></p>
```

this is my code

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.Load(htmlLocation);
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
{

   if (item.Name == "span")
   {
      HtmlNode div = doc.CreateElement("b");
      //what do i need to do here?
    }
}
```

i did a research and found this

```
http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode/M/InsertBefore
```

but i can't make it work.

i can't use

```
if (item.Name == "span")
   {

      item.Name = "newtag";
   }
```

because i need the value of the class. to decide which tag am i going to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the below code, you need to set `InnerHtml` and save Html document by calling save method `doc.Save(yourfilepath)`.

```
if (item.Name == "span")
{
  HtmlNode div = doc.CreateElement("b");
  div.InnerHtml = "Hello world";
  item.AppendChild(div);
  doc.Save(yourfilepath);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. i already tried a code similar to this before i posted here. And i tried it again with your code posted, and it doesn't work. it doesn't give me error. i even check if the if statment is triggered

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
var doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc1.LoadHtml("<p class=\"cs40314EBF\"><span class=\"cs1B16EEB5\">This is an ordinary text.</span></p>");

    foreach (var item in doc1.DocumentNode.Descendants())
    {
        if (item.Name == "span")
        {
            HtmlNode b = doc.CreateElement("b");
            b.InnerHtml = item.InnerText;
            item.ParentNode.AppendChild(b);
            item.Remove();
        }
    }
```